# Manually install Laravel package without composer

Tags: php, laravel-4, datatable, composer-php, laravel-5

I want to install `chumper/datatable` package in `Laravel 5` app. Its showing below error, since its not compatible with Laravel 5.

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
- Installation request for chumper/datatable ~2.3 -> satisfiable by chumper/datatable[2.3].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.2
- chumper/datatable 2.3 requires illuminate/config 4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/config[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
- don't install illuminate/config v4.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.2
```

So I checked out the git repo and found [this issue](https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable/issues/239) which suggest to change 4 line to make it work with Laravel 5.

The problem is how to Install `chumper/datatable` Manually since `composer` is going crazy with this. If you have any other idea please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just installed a fresh Laravel 5.0.4 and after that on require-dev "chumper/datatable": "dev-master" and it worked.

Comment: thanks, it worked, the problem was i should add dependency to `require-dev` not `require`